# External Disk hangs every diagnostic utilities

Tags: kernel, mount, hard-drive, dmesg

I am trying to get back my 1To, exFAT-formatted, external hard drive.

I cannot run anything on it or even mount it, everything hangs at a point where I can't even use Ctrl+C to finish it, my only thing left is to unplug my device.

So far I've been trying to run a lot a diagnostic and repair tools to try to save it.
In this order, I tried:

- ubuntu disk utility
- fdisk
- gparted
- badblocks
- smartctl
- dosfsck

The only thing giving me some output is `dmesg`. At plug it goes as follows (I deleted the time data for readabilty):

```
usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 25E1 1021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 0:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
ses 0:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
ses 0:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 13
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
ses 0:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
ses 0:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
ses 0:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
.ready
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953458176 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sda: sda1
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
```

And when I'm trying to mount (and only the mount operation) the disk I see quite a lot of kernel callstacks on dmesg but I'm not sure they could be useful.

Has anyone an (even) less invasive disk utility to get some useful data ? Or just an answer to my problem of course.

Comment: That "Failed to bind enclosure" may indicate that the enclosure may have problems.  Try the disk in another enclosure (or laptop slot), and try a known good disk in the enclosure to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @ubfan1 The drive has been tested on several computers and results don't differ, thanks though.